# JS if statement on window.screenY doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this code work, but for some reason the if statement dosent apply:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll",under);

function under() {
    if (window.screenY > 20) {
        console.log("over 20");
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        a.href = "http://google.com"; //the URL of 'popup' tab
        e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", under);      
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect screenY to change when you scroll? [screenY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenY) is the position of the browser's window relative to the monitor's box.

I guess you wanted [scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) instead.